# Notifications randomly stop being shown from Telegram

Tags: applications, notifications, background-process, android-13, telegram

I recently bought an Android 13 phone *(Ulefone Armor 24 if that matters)*, and I stumbled upon a problem that oftentimes I stop getting notifications from Telegram about new messages.

Judging by my research that might affect other apps. But I don't have any other app whose notifications I heavily rely upon to confirm or disprove that.

Further research showed that most of the times when that happens, if I go `Settings → Applications → Telegram`, I see that the `Stop` button is grayed out, which implies the Telegram background service got stopped.

At first I was blaming `Duraspeed`, which is default-enabled on this phone and presumably might cause such problems. But after I added Telegram to `Duraspeed` exceptions nothing changed. So apparently that is not it.

Today that problem got repeated, so I tried to peek at system logs with `adb logcat`, and found this hint:

```
12-16 03:01:01.577  1458  1489 I ActivityManager: Start proc 27895:com.pri.morning.kill/1000 for service {com.pri.morning.kill/com.pri.morning.kill.service.MorningKillService}
12-16 03:01:01.616  1458  2488 V ActivityManager: New death recipient com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$AppDeathRecipient@ffe6c1f for thread android.os.BinderProxy@33fab6c
12-16 03:06:58.537  1458  2790 D CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 171306433; UID 1000; state: ENABLED
12-16 03:06:58.537  1458  2790 D CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 218533173; UID 1000; state: ENABLED
12-16 03:06:58.541  1458  2790 V SettingsProvider: packageValueForCallResult, name = null, value : Bundle[{_track_generation=android.util.MemoryIntArray@bd, value=null, _generation_index=3, _generation=825}]
12-16 03:06:58.563  1458  1487 W UsageStatsService: Unexpected activity event reported! (ru.perekrestok.app/ru.perekrestok.app.presentation.MainActivity event : 23 instanceId : 37428045)
12-16 03:06:58.564  1458  2488 D WindowManager: setParent old=Task{a725e80 #844 type=standard A=10182:ru.perekrestok.app U=0 visible=false visibleRequested=false mode=fullscreen translucent=true sz=0},new=null,this window=ActivityRecord{a4602 u0 ru.perekrestok.app/.presentation.MainActivity} t844 f}},callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer.removeChild:772 com.android.server.wm.TaskFragment.removeChild:2592 com.android.server.wm.Task.removeChild:1499 com.android.server.wm.Task.removeChild:1482 com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer.removeImmediately:828 com.android.server.wm.WindowToken.removeImmediately:350
12-16 03:06:58.567  1458  2488 D WindowManager: setParent old=DefaultTaskDisplayArea@84346286,new=null,this window=Task{a725e80 #844 type=standard A=10182:ru.perekrestok.app U=0 visible=false visibleRequested=false mode=fullscreen translucent=true sz=0},callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer.removeChild:772 com.android.server.wm.TaskDisplayArea.removeChildTask:359 com.android.server.wm.TaskDisplayArea.removeChild:350 com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer.removeImmediately:828 com.android.server.wm.TaskFragment.removeImmediately:2672 com.android.server.wm.Task.removeImmediately:2587
12-16 03:06:58.578  1458  1478 I ActivityManager: Killing 23027:ru.letobank.Prometheus:pushservice/u0a184 (adj 920): remove task
12-16 03:06:58.579  1458  1478 I ActivityManager: Killing 22707:ru.letobank.Prometheus/u0a184 (adj 910): remove task
12-16 03:06:58.595  1458  2488 D ActivityManager: Calling pid 27895 killed pid 26945
12-16 03:06:58.601  1458  2488 I ActivityManager: Force stopping org.telegram.messenger appid=10181 user=0: from pid 27895
12-16 03:06:58.602  1458  2488 I ActivityManager: Killing 24470:org.telegram.messenger/u0a181 (adj 700): stop org.telegram.messenger due to from pid 27895
12-16 03:06:58.610  1458  2488 W ActivityTaskManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{8102054 u0 org.telegram.messenger/.DefaultIcon} t846 f}}: app died, no saved state
12-16 03:06:58.611  1458  1487 W UsageStatsService: Unexpected activity event reported! (org.telegram.messenger/org.telegram.ui.LaunchActivity event : 23 instanceId : 221610919)
12-16 03:06:58.613  1458  2488 D WindowManager: setParent old=ActivityRecord{8102054 u0 org.telegram.messenger/.DefaultIcon} t846 f}},new=null,this window=Window{1ea58b4 u0 org.telegram.messenger/org.telegram.messenger.DefaultIcon},callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer.removeChild:772 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.removeChild:4475 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.removeChild:388 com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer.removeImmediately:828 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeImmediately:2514 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeIfPossible:2704
12-16 03:06:58.617  1458  2488 D WindowManager: setParent old=Task{ded0031 #846 type=standard A=10181:org.telegram.messenger U=0 visible=false visibleRequested=false mode=fullscreen translucent=true sz=0},new=null,this window=ActivityRecord{8102054 u0 org.telegram.messenger/.DefaultIcon} t846 f}},callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer.removeChild:772 com.android.server.wm.TaskFragment.removeChild:2592 com.android.server.wm.Task.removeChild:1499 com.android.server.wm.Task.removeChild:1482 com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer.removeImmediately:828 com.android.server.wm.WindowToken.removeImmediately:350
12-16 03:06:58.620  1458  2488 D WindowManager: setParent old=DefaultTaskDisplayArea@84346286,new=null,this window=Task{ded0031 #846 type=standard A=10181:org.telegram.messenger U=0 visible=false visibleRequested=false mode=fullscreen translucent=true sz=0},callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer.removeChild:772 com.android.server.wm.TaskDisplayArea.removeChildTask:359 com.android.server.wm.TaskDisplayArea.removeChild:350 com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer.removeImmediately:828 com.android.server.wm.TaskFragment.removeImmediately:2672 com.android.server.wm.Task.removeImmediately:2587
12-16 03:06:58.625  1458  2488 I ActivityManager:   Force stopping service ServiceRecord{ec3cd7a u0 org.telegram.messenger/.NotificationRepeat}
```

So apparently some `MorningKillService` appears and just kills everything on left and right. And there is no matches on the internet for that word ATM. Any idea what is this about?

Comment: Trying to search the word `kill` over the settings came up with some built-in app called "Smart Killer", with "Disable" button grayed out and only "Force stop" being active. No idea what is that. Tried "force stop"ping the app, will see if that changes anything.

Comment: Seen this? https://www.reddit.com/r/ulefone/comments/ls2y5w/ulefone_armor_7_and_background_app/

Comment: @beeshyams thanks, no, I didn't; however the post is about Duraspeed app which I found on my own *(thankfully at random times it posts a notification that it suppressed some apps)*, and as I mentioned in the post I added Telegram to its exceptions. So unless there's some bug in Duraspeed regarding its exceptions, it's not the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That is unfortunately a quite common problem with cheaper brands - they're gaming the battery life metrics by very aggresively terminating apps in background and preventing them from receiving messages. They usually have some kind of allowlist for most known messaging apps, but Telegram commonly doesn't make a cut.

There's even a website dedicated to that problem: https://dontkillmyapp.com/

Usually it's possible to allowlist Telegram by finding an option related to smart battery savings, "app killer", "app suspend" or "app blocker".

In case of Ulefone, **it's probably called "Duraspeed"**, here's Threema's entry on how to allowlist it - for Telegram it will probably be the same: https://threema.ch/en/faq/push_ulefone_armor_8

Comment: I mentioned Duraspeed both in my question and in the comments to someone else who brought it up  I found indeed battery-related settings about restricting rarely used apps, however the list does not include Telegram. I'll write an email to Ulefone on Monday if no ideas would come up, but as it stands I tried everything that was mentioned.